# How to read the member/child node of a descendant?

Tags: c#, xml

I am new to XML. How do I read the member/child node of a descendant?

```xml
<ho> 
    <pro NAME="J1">
        <type>C1</type>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <sta ID="A">Junk1</sta>
        <sta ID="B">Junk2</sta>
    </pro>
    <pro NAME="J2">
        <type>C2</type>
        <ID>3</ID>
        <sta ID="A">Junk3</sta>
        <sta ID="B">Junk4</sta>
    </pro>
</ho>
```

```csharp
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);
foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("pro"))
{
    string pro_attribute = element.Attribute("NAME").Value;
    //I can get pro_attribute J2 
    if ( pro_attribute =="J2")
    {
        //how to get getJunk 3 and 4 without having to 
        //read/loop through Junk1 and 2
        foreach (XElement element1 in doc.Descendants("sta"))
        {
            //I could do this, but it will start with Junk 1. 
            //I want to start with Junk3 instead
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: instead u could use a switch case to achieve the same

Comment: something like this- XmlNodeList subList = title.ChildNodes;    
   IEnumerator enumList = subList.GetEnumerator();
   while(enumList.MoveNext())
   {
    XmlNode xNode = (XmlNode) enumList.Current;
    switch(xNode.Name)
    {
     case "Junk1" : 
           
           break;
     case "Junk2"   :
           
           break;
     case "Junk3"   :
           
           break;
     case "Junk4"   :
           
           break;

     default: break;
    }
   }

Comment: Are you trying to skip the first element? if so, you can use

doc.Descendants("pro").Skip(1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a little Linq

```
var result = doc.Descendants("pro")
                .Select(p => new
                {
                    Name = p.Attribute("NAME").Value,
                    Type = (string)p.Element("type"),
                    ID = (string)p.Element("ID"),
                    Stas = p.Descendants("sta")
                            .Select(sta => new
                            {
                                ID = sta.Attribute("ID").Value,
                                Value = (string)sta
                            }).ToList()
                })
                .ToList();
```

You can use `XPath` too:

```
var result = doc.XPathSelectElements("//pro[@NAME='J2']")
                .......
                .......
```

Comment: I need to insert IF before "select". I only want to get certain "pro" and not all. how to do this?

Comment: like `.Where(p=>p.(string)p.Element("type")=="XXXXX")`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
    foreach(XElement element1 in doc.Descendents("sta"))
```

to

```
    foreach(XElement staElement in element.Elements("sta"))
```

Because element object now points to j2 and you can use the method Elements to get the list of elements you are interested in and iterate through it.

Comment: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' because 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: But Elements w ill return IEnumerable am I missing anything here.